# Displaying data from database based on specific values Codeigniter 3

Tags: database, codeigniter, routes, parameter-passing, codeigniter-3

I don't know how to explain this but i hope you can get the glimpse about my problem.
I have list of *kode_mtk*, if i click the button **Input** it will direct to view list  of student who takes that subject.

[image]

I want to display that list of student based on **kode_mtk** and **kelas**. i tried to put $kode_mtk and $kelas in model and controller but it doesn't works.
I hope you can guide me well since i'm newbie in codeigniter.

This is my controller :

```
public function display(){
    $data['nama'] = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $kode_mtk = $this->input->post('kode_mtk');
    $kelas = $this->input->post('kelas');
    $data['hasil'] = $this->mtk_model->hasil();     

    $this->load->view('templates/header_tutor',$data);      
    $this->load->view('tutor/daftar_mtk_np', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer_tutor');

}
```

This is my model :

```
function hasil () {

    $data = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $kode_mtk = $this->input->post('kode_mtk');
    $kelas = $this->input->post('kelas');
    $this->db->select('
        tb_kelas.idtutor,
        tb_kelas.nim,
        tb_kelas.nama,
        tb_kelas.masa,
        tb_kelas.kelas,
        tb_kelas.idtutorial,
        tb_mtk.kode_mtk,
        tb_mtk.kode_program_studi,
        prodi.nama_program_studi

    ');
    $this->db->from('tb_kelas');
    $this->db->join('tb_mtk', 'tb_mtk.idtutorial = tb_kelas.idtutorial');       
    $this->db->join('prodi', 'prodi.kode_program_studi = tb_mtk.kode_program_studi');
    $this->db->where('tb_kelas.idtutor',$data);
    $this->db->where('tb_kelas.masa',20172);
    $this->db->where('tb_mtk.kode_mtk',$kode_mtk);
    $this->db->where('tb_kelas.kelas',$kelas);      

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

And here is my view

```html
<div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">
 <div class="form-group">
   <table class="table table-hover">
  <tr>  
   <th>No</th> 
   <th>NIM</th>  
   <th>NAMA</th>      
   <th>KELAS</th>
   <th>KODE MTK</th>
   <th>PRODI</th>
   <th>N.AKHIR</th>
   <th>AKSI</th>
  </tr>
  <?php  
     if(isset($hasil)>0){$i=1; foreach($hasil as $row)  {  
     ?>  
    <tr>  
     <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>  
     <td><?php echo $row->nim; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->nama; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->kelas; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->kode_mtk; ?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row->nama_program_studi; ?></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="form-control na" id="na<?php echo $i; ?>" name="na" readonly /></td>
     <td>Input Nilai<td>
     
    </tr>  
   <?php $i++;}}?> 
   </form>
   </table>
 </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: What is the error message do you get?

Comment: Is the problem, that the post does not contain the two variables `kode_mtk` and `kelas`? Or is it another problem?

Comment: @HastaDhana i don't get the error message.. the view doesn't give me the results that i want

Comment: @PhilippMaurer yes, i think the post doesn't give me back the two variables, i tried to put $kode_mtk = $this->input->post('kode_mtk') & $kelas = $this->input->post('kelas') in controller and model but it doesn't display anything. I must be missing something here..

Answer (score 0):

So, i found the mistakes. I changed **$this->input->post** to **$this->input->get** and put this in model. So in controller i just load $data['hasil'] = $this->mtk_model->hasil(); 
Thanks for your comments all :)